# Change Spring JPA repository to one related to HIVE/HADOOP

Tags: spring, hadoop, hive, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I am working on a project integrating Hadoop, Hive and accessing it via Spring.

Currently my project works with a default Spring repository: "org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository@757b7c0a" but I would want to work with a repository able to understand HIVE queries. 
For example, inserting a user into a HIVE database.

Actually I have a connection to HIVE in my project but everything is chaos and nothing works and I believe it is because the repository I am using is not the correct one.

So my question is ... how, where and what values to insert in order to change that repository for a Hive-friendly one ?

I have this in my application.yml:

```
spring:
profiles:
    include: swagger, no-liquibase
devtools:
    restart:
        enabled: true
    livereload:
        enabled: false # we use gulp + BrowserSync for livereload
datasource:
    type: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
    url: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=0
    username: catalin
    password:
    default-auto-commit: true
jpa:
  show-sql: true
  properties:
    hibernate:
        format_sql: true

mail:
    host: localhost
    port: 25
    username:
    password:
thymeleaf:
    cache: false

liquibase:
    contexts: hive
```

Thank you.